# Install Mastodon on Owncloud server

Tags: node.js, vps, owncloud, mastodon

I'm trying to install Mastodon in my own vps with debian in the same vps where i run an Owncloud server.

Actually I'm following 2 guides at the same time, trying to figure out how to place all things togheter.

Owncloud let you choose what kind of project you want to create, like nodejs, php, html and i choose Nodejs here, that run on port 3000. Owncloud let you run your projects on nginx.

So i create a new Nodejs project, i have my custom domain that point on the server as other websites on the same server do, and i have my own smtp email.

So the only steps i'm changing in the installation instructions is where i place the mastodon files, that i place in the folder created by owncloud in the /home/mywebsite/htdocs/mywebsitedomain/ path and then i change the nginx configuration file too, via Owncloud that have a basic vhost file when you create the project, using the previous path as root folder.

Also, i make a lets encrypt certificate with owncloud on the domain, then i uncomment the ssl lines in the configuration file and save it and it does not give me error.

Well this does not work. I get error 502 bad gateway if i do like this, and i get other error if i just follow the official guide by first step to last, ignoring only the nodejs installation as i already have it with owncloud, i think.

(BELOW I CHANGE domain.it with MYDOMAIN as stackoverflow may consider it spam)

This is the default vhost file for Owncloud created project:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name MYDOMAIN;
  return 301 https://www.MYDOMAIN$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name www.MYDOMAIN www1.MYDOMAIN;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:{{app_port}}/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }
}
```

And this is the new one i'm placing, taken by mastodon installations instructions and modified as needed (i think)

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream streaming {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000 fail_timeout=0;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=CACHE:10m inactive=7d max_size=1g;

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomain.it;
  root /home/social-slam/htdocs/www.MYDOMAIN/mastodon/live/public;
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { allow all; }
  location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mydomain.it;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!NULL:!SHA;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # Uncomment these lines once you acquire a certificate:
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN/privkey.pem;

  keepalive_timeout    70;
  sendfile             on;
  client_max_body_size 80m;

  root /home/social-slam/htdocs/www.MYDOMAIN/mastodon/live/public;

  gzip on;

gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  # If Docker is used for deployment and Rails serves static files,
  # then needed must replace line `try_files $uri =404;` with `try_files $uri @proxy;`.
  location = /sw.js {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=604800, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/avatars/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/emoji/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

 location ~ ^/headers/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/packs/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/shortcuts/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/sounds/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, must-revalidate";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/system/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2419200, immutable";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; form-action 'none'";
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

   location ^~ /api/v1/streaming {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Proxy "";

    proxy_pass http://streaming;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";

    tcp_nodelay on;
  }

  location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    proxy_pass_header Server;

    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_cache CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 7d;
    proxy_cache_valid 410 24h;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

    tcp_nodelay on;
  }

  error_page 404 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

If someone can help me to understand what i'm doing wrong, it will be awesome.

Comment: This is rather a question for https://serverfault.com.